# How to upload a file in JSF portlet in Liferay 6.0.6

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, liferay, portlet

I'm developing a JSF 2.0 portlet for Liferay 6.0.6 (Plugins SDK 6.1) and I need file upload functionality. I tried the following different solutions without success:

- [Tomahawk](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/02/uploading-files-with-jsf.html)
- [overriding `ActionRequest` processing](http://www.portalteam.net/blogs/using-file-upload-in-liferay-jsf-portlet)
- `bridge:inputFile` component

Any suggestion how to do it is welcomed, also hacks or using other technologies than JSF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a standard HTML form so:

```
<form action="your_action_goes_here" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then in your Java code override the processAction method (usually in a class that extends GenericPortlet or maybe Liferay's MVCPortlet or JSPPortlet (for 5.2.3)) and then you can get the file itself by:

```
public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) {
    UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
    File file = (File) uploadRequest.getFile("file");
    // Do something with your file here
}
```

Job done! :) This is only skeleton code, and there will be exception handling you need to do but your IDE will help with that.

~~ EDIT ~~~

Other possible solution maybe to use:

```
 HttpServletRequest req = FacesUtil.getRequest();
 UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(req);
```

This I got from: http://ironicprogrammer.blogspot.com/2010/03/file-upload-in-jsf2.html

Is that any help?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too (http://www.portalteam.net/blogs/using-file-upload-in-liferay-jsf-portlet) overriding org.portletfaces.bridge.GenericFacesPortlet. The problem here is that processAction was never called (only the processEvent(EventRequest eventRequest, EventResponse eventResponse) )and therefore I cannot get File. 

I tried to call PortalUtil.getUploadPortelRequest in other place, but still was unable to get the file...

Comment: I've found another possible solution, don't know if it'll work on not but thought I'd post and see! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSF standard [`h:inputFile`](https://liferayfaces.org/web/guest/jsf-showcase/-/jsf-tag/h/inputfile/general) tag (or **any file upload tag from any popular component suite**):

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile value="#{bean.uploadedPart}" />
</h:form>
```

---

```
private Part uploadedPart;

public Part getUploadedPart() {
    return uploadedPart;
}

public void setUploadedPart(Part uploadedPart) {
    this.uploadedPart = uploadedPart;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The **bridge:inputFile** component of [PortletFacesBridge 2.0.1](http://www.portletfaces.org/projects/portletfaces-bridge) works for me on Liferay 6.1 EE for a Portlet 2.0 portlet using JSF 2.0. Because we're using Primefaces (v3.2), I also tried to use its [uploadcomponent](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadHome.jsf), but that [doesn't work in portlets](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2905) yet. It's being worked on for a [future version of the PortletFacesBridge/Primefaces](http://www.portletfaces.org/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/206621).

What worked for me was:

xhtml:

```
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:bridge="http://portletfaces.org/bridge">

...
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <bridge:inputFile id="icon" binding="#{bean.attachment}" />
    </h:form>
...
```

bean:

```
import org.portletfaces.bridge.component.UploadedFile

...

private transient HtmlInputFile attachment;

...

public HtmlInputFile getAttachment() {
    return attachment;
}

public void setAttachment(HtmlInputFile attachment) {
    this.attachment = attachment;
}

public String addApplication() {
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = attachment.getUploadedFile();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have successfully used file upload component of [Primefaces v3.2](http://primefaces.org/) and the built in bridge:inputFile with [Liferay-Faces v3.1.0-RC1](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/overview)  on Liferay-6.1-EE. Still a release candidate but pretty stable. 
Did not use advanced features of Primefaces upload component though. 
Thanks to Mr. Neil Griffin and several others in doing an excellent job on making JSF 2.x work in portlet environment.